# PSexec access is denied on domain user

Tags: psexec

I seem to be having some trouble with only 2/150+ users when using psexec. I am mapping to their profile and get the "Access is denied" message.

I don't understand how that could be since every user is setup the same and I can access the rest.

I am running CMD as an admin and then passing through our admin credentials when connecting:

psexec.exe \\test-pc -u test\administrator -p testing cmd

Any ideas where to investigate? I tried looking for any differences in the accounts but couldn't find any.

Comment: please give more detailed information. your example looks like trying to connect to a pc with a the local administrator user. is the pc domain integrated? are you executing it on the same pc for 150 users? what does "mapping to their profile" mean? if access is denied you need to investigate on that pc. can you RDP into that pc where you get the psexec access denied message? you might check the security log file on that pc for EventID 4624 / An account was successfully logged on essages.

Comment: The PC is on the domain, as well as the other 150+ PC's. We are connecting with the domain admin. By  mapping to their profile, I just mean cd/ - cd users - cd "user" which is where I get access denied. I am able to remote in or just use the admin $ to access his folder which is why I don't understand why I get access denied in psexec.

Comment: you are mapping all users on all 150+ PCs? or specific users on specific PCs? "cd user" from where? is there a full path? a relative path? again you need to provide more specific information. maybe the profile of those two users is in a temp profile, or the profile had an issue and has a different path. you should log on to the PC with administrator and check if the path exists. I have a user who instead of "c:\users\<samaccountname>" has the path "c:\users\<samaccountname>.<short domain name> due to some profile issues and just to mention it as an example.